# How to match uri-collection results using templates

Tags: xslt, xpath, uri

I have variable with collection of files URIs.

```
<xsl:variable name="swiftFilesPath" select="concat($inputPath, '?select=*.swift;recurse=yes;on-error=warning')"/>
<xsl:variable name="swiftFiles" select="uri-collection($swiftFilesPath)"/>
```

I want to use apply-templates to process through all URIs.

For now I'm using for-each for getting files and then process through each line.

```
<xsl:for-each select="$swiftFiles">
    [...]
    <xsl:variable name="filePath" select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="fileContent" select="unparsed-text($filePath, $encoding)"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($fileContent, '\n')">
        [...]
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I am thinking about changing it to something like this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$swiftFiles" mode="swiftFiles"/>
[...]

<xsl:template match="*" mode="swiftFiles">
    [...]
</xsl:template/>
```

1. Will it be better approach to processing files? I mean `apply-templates` better than `for-each`.
2. Is there a way to avoid `"*"` in template match? Maybe something like "*[. castable as xs:anyURI]"?

Comment: Adding XSLT 3.0 tag as `uri-collection()` requires XSLT 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I don't think there's anything to gain from using apply-templates unless there's some kind of dynamic despatch going on. For example, if you had both .txt URIs and .xml URIs then you could do

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="uri-collection(....)" mode="dereference"/>

<xsl:template match=".[ends-with(., '.txt')]" mode="dereference">
  --- process unparsed text file ----
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match=".[ends-with(., '.xml')]" mode="dereference">
  --- process XML file ----
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="." mode="dereference"/>
```

But if they are all processed the same way, then xsl:for-each does the job perfectly well.

I've answered your second question by using "." as the pattern that matches everything (atomic values included). The pattern "*" will only match element nodes.